# MySQL: Delete field that's greater than other field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have data like this

```
id field1   field2
1    7        1
2    0        3
3    2        9
4    2        8
5    18       6
```

i want to delete all rows which field2 number greater than 3 times the number in field1

should it be something like this?

```
 $sql = "delete from data where field2 > 3(field1)";
```

Comment: This should do it: `DELETE FROM data WHERE field2 > 3 * field1`

Comment: What happened when you tried it; or did you?

Comment: @Alex Howansky thanks:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just have to add `*` like :

```
DELETE FROM data WHERE field2 > 3 * field1
```